# Not dcommitting every change made to svn using git-svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have an SVN repo that I have copied in my PC and I've been making some changes and commits. I make a commit for every code issue I solve (that I've been asked to solve). If I'm in the process of solving one, I just save the code and leave it on my computer (until I solve it, that I commit it). I'm using `git svn`.

Today I've solved three issues (and so made three commits) and I left the code in the process of solving another one. I want to push (`dcommit`) all commits I've made locally.

The thing is: I still have files that have not been committed and, when I try to `dcommit` I get "needs update" for every one of them.

How can I `git svn dcommit` only what I have done `git add` to in my local repo? I want to do just what `git push` does, and have all my unversioned files/diffs untouched.

I know this is probably malpractice or something, but there goes my workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think you need to run `git svn fetch` in order to be able to see what other developers have been doing on the svn branch you are trying to push onto. Then, in order to be able to do actual work to push your changes and stuff, you will have to stop what you are doing and clean up the working tree. In order to do that run `git stash save`. Then you should be able to move around at ease. Now, you should rebase on top of the updated tip of the svn branch and now you should be able to run `git svn dcommit` to push into svn. Then you might consider getting what you had stashed poped out so you can continue working `git stash pop`.

**Edit:**

> [Since git 2.16](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash/2.16.0#git-stash-save-p--patch-k--no-keep-index-u--include-untracked-a--all-q--quietltmessagegt) `git stash save` *is deprecated in favour of* `git stash push`*. It differs from "stash push" in that it cannot take pathspecs, and any non-option arguments form the message.*

Comment: About the `fetch`: I'm sure I'm the only one that commits to the branch. Apart from that, what do `git stash save` and `git stash pop` do? I don't know a lot of git in general, just basic things such as push/pull/fetch/commit/checkout/init. I actually chose to use Git-SVN as I've had some (actually only basic) git experience before.

Comment: the stash allows you to save incomplete work (that is not ready to be committed) cleaning up your working tree and recover it later when you want to get back so you can continue working on that incomplete work... just what you are asking for.

Comment: It worked! And, reading the documentation for git, I found that `git stash save` [has been deprecated](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash/2.16.0#git-stash-save-p--patch-k--no-keep-index-u--include-untracked-a--all-q--quietltmessagegt) since `git 2.16` in favour of `git stash push`. Also the SVN push command is actually `git svn dcommit`.

Comment: Yeah.... aware of both things. Have to get used to use push (the stash is a stack, so it makes sense to use push instead of save)... and dcommit? Oh, I see... I said `git push dcommit`, not `git svn dcommit`... that was my muscle memory in action. I know it's `git svn dcommit`. Let me correct it on the recipe.